# Xpath - Only Price

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, ui-automation

If I want to determine the price with python using xpath, it works fine so far. Unfortunately, I get unattractive additional characters from the website.
Can I cut the price somehow?

```
XPATH_PRICE = '//span[contains(@class,"price")]/text()'
```

The result is for example:

```
"PRICE": "79,49 \u00e2\u0082\u00ac",
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Can you share HTML code sample for the same and the code you're using?

Comment: you may not able to do it with xpath. It might need some text processing.

Answer (score 0):

### I suggest two ways:

**First:** You can just cut the string

```
value = '"PRICE": "79,49 \u00e2\u0082\u00ac",'
print(value[10:-5])
#   prints 79,49
```

**Second:** You can use a regular expression

```
import re

value = '"PRICE": "79,49 \u00e2\u0082\u00ac",'
print(re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*,\d+|\d+", value))
#   prints ['79,49']
```

*The second way is preferable.*

Comment: Thank you Alex. Nice :) I have solved it now in such a way that I shortened the individual elements with.strip() before the conversion.

Comment: You are welcome. You can answer on your own question to show your solution.